# Other kinds of equivalence relations on the set of idempotents of a Banach or $C^*$-algebra or a ring (Can we get a new kind of K-theory?)

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, banach-algebras

The standard equivalent relations on idempotents of a $C^*$ algebra or a Banach algebra are Murray von Neumann, similarity and homotopy equivalent. In this post we consider two other kinds of equivalence relations which can be defined in the context of pure algebras and rings. Here we explain about these relations (our algebra structure is denoted by $A$ which is regarded as a ring, algebra, or Banach or $C^*$-algebra):

> 1. Two idempotents $e,f\in A$ are equivalent if there is an automorphism $\phi$ of $A$ with $\phi(e)=f$. This equivalence relation is well-behaved in the sense that it preserves the embeding $a\mapsto a\oplus 0$ from $A\to M_2(A)$. Hence it can be defined on the inductive limit $A\to M_2(A)\to \ldots \to M_{2^n} (A)\ldots$

> 2)Two idempotents $e_1,e_2$ are equivalent if the ring structure of localization of $A$ along the two sets $\{1,e_i\}$ is independent of $i=1,2$.

**Questions:**

Are these equivalent relations well behaved in the sense of preserving by the natural embedding $a\mapsto a\oplus 0$ from $M_n(A) \to M_{n+1}(A)$?

Can we get a new kind of K-theory if we apply one of these two equivalent relations (by consideration  of the inductive limit $M_n(A)\to M_{n+1}(A)$ or $M_{2^n}(A) \to M_{2^{n+1}}(A)$)?

If the answer is yes, what would be the  commutative aspects of this K-theory, that is the topological interpretations of this K-theory for algebra $C(X)$ where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space?

**Note:** In order to equipe the structure under discussion with a group operation we need to consider [the questions in this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348919/automorphism-of-algebras-with-certain-initial-conditions-on-given-idempotents).

Comment: Many years ago Joachim Cuntz proved a result, which became known as the "Cuntz trap", stating that if you came up with any functor from C*-algebras to abelian groups with minimal sensible properties you were in fact reinventing K-theory, or perhaps KK-theory with a fixed first argument.

Comment: @Tomasz,  I am sorry but I don't understand what do you mean by that.    In case  you believe   I'm being offensive in any way, please let me know it so that I could perhaps correct any unintended misstep.

Comment: @Ruy I  would  appreciated if  you introduce me that reference.

Comment: See "Cuntz, Joachim; K-theory and C*-algebras. Algebraic K-theory, number theory, geometry and analysis (Bielefeld, 1982), 55–79, Lecture Notes in Math., 1046, Springer, 1984."  The results you want are in section 6.

Comment: @Ruy thank you very much for the reference!